# Generic collection of generic classes?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have a class that I fill from the database:

```
public class Option<T>
{
  public T Value { get; set; }
  public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
  public List<T> AvailableValues { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a collection of them:

```
List<Option<T>> list = new List<Option<T>>();
Option<bool> TestBool = new Option<bool>();
TestBool.Value = true;
TestBool.DefaultValue = false;
list.Add(TestBool);
Option<int> TestInt = new Option<int>();
TestInt.Value = 1;
TestInt.DefaultValue = 0;
list.Add(TestInt);
```

It doesn't seem to work. Ideas?

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it doesn't seem to work?"

Comment: @Dave, iandisme: It won't compile. "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you really want a nongeneric base class - otherwise there's really nothing in common between the different `Option<T>` closed types.

I understand what you're trying to do, but .NET generics don't allow you to express that relationship. It's like trying to do a map from `Type` to an instance of that type... it just doesn't fly :(

Answer (score 7):

You have to provide a type instead of your template parameter:

`List<Option<T>> list = new List<Option<T>>();`

becomes

`List<Option<bool>> list = new List<Option<bool>>();`

Adding items of type `Option<int>` to that same list won't work, but that is a separate issue than what I've addressed above.

Answer (score 0):

Firts line you must say wich type T is.

```
List<Option<bool>> list = new List<Option<bool>>();
```

And also you can't put that TestInt in this list...

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing only works with heterogeneous lists.

`List<T>` is an homogeneous list of type `T`, meaning *all* elements have to be of type `T`. Because `Option<bool>` and `Option<int>` do not have a common ancestor other than `object` you can't do that unless you use a `List<object>` or the old `ArrayList`, both of which act as heterogeneous lists.

Think of retrieving objects from that list:

```
list.Add(TestBool);
list.Add(TestInt);

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
   list[i].Value // <- what's the type of this?
}
```